# Show/Hide elements based on the ID of both targets

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off, I'd like to apologize in advance if this is a duplicate, I'm sure the solution is already out there, but I just couldn't find the right way to phrase my searches so I came up empty handed.

I'm trying to build a lengthy form and hide sections of it until they are needed. Rather than creating a function for each of my 20+ sections, I am trying to create one "master" function that will show the appropriate `div`.

My plan is to have the `id` for the checkbox that will show the section be something along the lines of `id="test"` and the section to be shown will have `id="test_2"`. Then in the JS I will simply append the `_2` to the code that will select the target to show.

Below is my code that simply doesn't show the `div` when needed. Any thoughts on how to get this working, or, even better, a more appropriate solution? Thanks!

JS

```
$(".show").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "1" ) {
        $("#"+this.attr('id')+"_2").slideDown("fast");
    } 
    else {
        $("#"+this.attr('id')+"_2").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="show" value="1" name="test" id="test" />
<div id="test_2">
    Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data attributes is the magic word:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="show" value="1" name="test" data-id="test" />
<div id="test">
    Hello World
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".show").on('change', function(){
    $("#" + $(this).data('id'))[this.checked?'slideUp':'slideDown']('fast');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/D8VbC/)

doing it this way, it doesn't matter what your markup looks like, it gets the right element everytime, and it's easy to just set the ID in the data attribute.

sidenote: won't the value of the checkbox always be `1`, are you really trying to see if it's checked or not

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to see if it is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative selectors, so you can do away with IDs.

```
$(".show").change(function(){
   if ($(this).val() == "1" ) {
        $(this).next('div').slideDown("fast");
    } 
    ...etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get id like `this.id`

dont forget use `===` instead of `==`

```
$(".show").on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val() === "1" ) {
        $("#"+ this.id + "_2").slideDown("fast");
    } 
    else {
        $("#"+this.id + "_2").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```